# Split page into 2 using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maps

I want **data** to be displayed in angular on left side of page and **map** on right side of page all using `angular`. Any idea what to use exactly

- [Splitting the screens in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749999/splitting-the-screens-in-angularjs)
- [Split Angular template into multiple small templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397748/split-angular-template-into-multiple-small-templates)

These links I have found and many other using `i-frames` but I don't find them useful in my case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What map do you want to be displayed? What do you mean by split? Please explain a bit more what you want to achieve.

Comment: the entire page is split into two sections. The left side you display any table or data and right side you display map. As I mentioned above. Like on pages you have advertisements on half side and other half data. that kind of page I want not for advertisements though but for data and map.